# Create a service that points to a SRV DNS record

Tags: kubernetes

On Kubernetes, I can create a `Service`, and then an `Endpoint` which points to a set of external IP addresses, so I can have that `service` available inside the cluster. For example:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    targetPort: 9200

---

kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.128.1.2
  - ip: 10.128.1.3
  - ip: 10.128.1.4
  - ip: 10.128.1.5
  ports:
  - port: 9200
```

This is nice, but it is a pain to keep it updated.

I thought maybe I could create a `Service` with an `ExternalName`, but I'm not sure if it round robin or just cache the `DNS` result and use it directly:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-dns
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: elasticsearch.foo.bar
```

Is there a way to create a service on Kubernetes, from an external DNS, which round robin the requests to the DNS multiple IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When any application looks up the name `elasticsearch-dns`, the Cluster DNS returns a CNAME record with value `elasticsearch.foo.bar`. So there is no caching of IP or anything by kubernetes.

[From docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

> When looking up the host my-service.prod.svc.cluster.local, the
>   cluster DNS Service returns a CNAME record with the value
>   my.database.example.com. Accessing my-service works in the same way as
>   other Services but with the crucial difference that redirection
>   happens at the DNS level rather than via proxying or forwarding.